# Mule 3.6.1 - memory usage steadily increases - any known leaks?

Tags: memory, mule

I am using mule CE and built a HTTP reverse proxy. Things are working fine, however, mule's memory usage has steadily increased from 50% to 80% in 3 weeks. Are there any known memory issues with 3.6.1?

thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MuleSoft Jira and use the 'Affects Version' filter :
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8533?jql=affectedVersion%20%3D%203.6.1%20AND%20text%20~%20%22memory%20leak%22

This shows one result around using a VM monitor with Mule Standalone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run your application in MMC once and analyze the flow using flow analyzer to see which flow/component is consuming more thread and memory...